# Control filename stored in tar archive

Tags: tar

I want to make a tar archive containing various files scattered around the filesystem:

```
$ tar czvf outfile.tar.gz /some/file /some/other/filename
```

This creates the archive successfully, but when I extract it, the files are still in a directory tree matching the original locations:

```
$ tar xvf outfile.tar.gz
some/file
some/other/filename
```

I'd like to have them both extracted to the current directory, such that `file` and `filename` are created on their own.

I can do this at extract time using `--transform`, e.g.:

```
$ tar xvf outfile.tar.gz --transform=s,.*/,,
```

This does what I want, but it's a bit annoying to have to use an obscure option at extract-time, makes it more difficult to send to others, and so forth.

I could do it at create-time like this:

```
$ cd tmpdir
$ cp /some/file /some/other/filename .
$ tar czvf outfile.tar.gz *
```

But that seems a bit heavyweight, especially if there are large files or a lot of them.

Is there any way to control the filenames that `tar` stores at create-time directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't `--transform` work when creating the archive, then? It seems to work on my GNU tar 1.27.1:

```
$ tar czf out.tar.gz some/foo some/other/bar --transform=s,.*/,,
$ tar tzf out.tar.gz 
foo
bar
```

If it doesn't work, another possibility would be to make links to the files in the current directory (as you did with `cp`, but with `ln`):

```
$ ln /some/foo /some/other/bar .
$ tar czf out.tar.gz foo bar
```

Comment: That does work. All the Web examples I found used it only on extract, but seems it's incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very useful tool named [tardy](http://tardy.sourceforge.net/) that can be used to edit `tar` files:

```
tardy -Remove_Prefix 55 outfile.tar.gz transformed.tar.gz
```

Here `55` is an arbitrary number larger than the maximum depth of all directories in `outfile.tar.gz`.  `-Remove_Prefix 55` tells `tardy` to remove (at most) 55 leading directories from filenames.